# Does Windows Phone 8.1 have any fixed-width sans-serif fonts?

Tags: fonts, windows-phone-8.1

I need to make a TextBlock appear like an old-fashioned LCD display, e.g.

[image]

so I need a fixed-width, sans-serif font. Are there any available in Windows Phone 8.l

Comment: I see Consolas and Courier New in the XAML designer's combobox.  Not so sure how well it is filtered, just try it in the emulator.

Comment: Consolas is the way to go.